# How to create a class that will manage goods in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, class

I do not know how to create a class that will manage the goods.
1. Sort by price
2. Sort by name

I created a constructor that creates objects.

```
class Products {
        constructor(name,price,description,img){
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.description = description;
            this.img = img;
        }
    }
    var nike = new Products("Nike", 100, "new-shoes","img/nike.png");
    var adidas = new Products("Adidas", 120, "classic-shoes","img/adidas.png");
    var puma = new Products("Puma",150,"new-shoes","img/puma.png");
    var jordan = new Products("Jordan", 170, "outlet-shoes", "img/jordan.png");
    var converse = new Products("Converse",70,"outlet-shoes","img/convrse.png")
    var nikeAirMax = new Products("Nike Air Max", 200, "shoes","img/nikeAirMax.png");
    var newBal = new Products("New Balance 990",179,"new-shoes","img/newBal.png");
    var arrGoods = [nike,adidas,puma,jordan,nikeAirMax,converse,newBal];
```

Then created a function that displays the goods in the HTML file.

```
 function addGoods(item){
        for (let i = 0; i<arrGoods.length; i++){
                document.getElementById("products").innerHTML += `<div class="info-goods">
                <div class="img"><img src=${item[i].img}></div>
                <div class="name">${item[i].name}</div>
                <div class="price">${item[i].price}</div>
                <div class="description">${item[i].description}</div>
               </div>`
            }
    }
    addGoods(arrGoods);
```

created functions that are sorted (by price and by name)

```
 function sortByPrise() {
        var div = document.querySelector("#products");
        if (div){
            div.innerHTML = '';
            this.PriseSort(arrGoods);
            addGoods(arrGoods);
        };

    }

    function sortByName() {
        var div = document.querySelector("#products");
        if (div){
            div.innerHTML = '';
            nameSort(arrGoods);
            addGoods(arrGoods);
        };
    }

    function PriseSort(arr){
        arr.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.price - b.price;
        });
    };

    function nameSort(arr){
        arr.sort(function(a,b){
            if(a.name > b.name){
                return 1;
            }
            if (a.name < b.name){
                return -1;
```

How to add these functions to another class (for example, class Menedger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add all of the data into an array of objects.
2. Pass a selector string and the array of objects to the constructor. The selector is for the `<table>` (a table is far better than divs but it can be easily changed if divs are preferred)
3. Add a method that will add rows from a given array of objects. *see `.addRows()` in demo.*
4. Add a method that sorts an array of objects and passes it along to `.addRows()`. *see `.sortCol()` in demo.*
5. As a bonus the `<th>` will sort by column when clicked. The callback isn't part of the `class` because it's way out of the scope of the question.

```js
const items = [
  {name: "Nike", price: 100, desc: "new-shoes", img: "https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/nike-xxl.png"},
  {name: "Adidas", price: 120, desc: "classic-shoes", img:"https://www.vouchercodes.co.uk/static/v10/images/merchant/logo/128px/1524_160119151356.png"},
  {name: "Puma",price: 150,desc: "new-shoes", img:"https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/puma-logo-png-1.png"},
  {name: "Jordan", price: 170, desc: "outlet-shoes",  img:"https://www.svgimages.com/svg-image/s8/air-jordan-logo-256x256.png"},
  {name: "Converse",price: 70,desc: "outlet-shoes", img:"https://d13genyhhfmqry.cloudfront.net/widget/mp_340806_2019-04-06-01-57-52-000851.jpg"},
  {name: "Nike Air Max",price:  200,desc:  "shoes", img:"https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/nike-xxl.png"},
  {name: "New Balance 990",price: 179,desc: "new-shoes", img:"https://www.vouchercodes.co.uk/static/v10/images/merchant/logo/128px/4484_160309151253.png"}];
  
class Products {
  constructor(selector, items) {
    this.table = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.items = [...items];
  }

  addRows(array) {
    const rng = document.createRange();
    rng.selectNodeContents(this.table);
    rng.deleteContents();
    for (let item of array) {
      let row = `
        <tr>
          <td><img src='${item.img}' width='50'></td>
          <td>${item.name}</td>
          <td>${item.price}</td>
          <td>${item.desc}</td>
        </tr>`;
      this.table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
    }
  }

  sortCol(key = 'name', descending = false) {
    if (this.items[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const compare = key => {
        return (a, b) => {
          if (a[key] < b[key]) return descending ? 1 : -1;
          if (a[key] > b[key]) return descending ? -1 : 1;
          return 0;
        };
      };
      let sorted = this.items.sort(compare(key));
      this.addRows(sorted);
    }
    return false;
  }

}
const shoes = new Products('.main', items);
shoes.addRows(items);
const head = document.querySelector('.head');

function callback(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.matches('th')) {
    let key = clicked.className;
    if (clicked.dataset.dir === '1') {
      shoes.sortCol(key, true);
      clicked.dataset.dir = '0';
    } else {
      shoes.sortCol(key);
      clicked.dataset.dir = '1';
    }
  }
  return false;
}
head.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

```html
<table class='catalog'>
  <thead class='head'>
    <tr>
      <th class='name' data-dir='0' colspan='2'>Name</th>
      <th class='price' data-dir='0'>Price</th>
      <th class='desc' data-dir='0'>Desc</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='main'></tbody> 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not make the products in the product class. Just keep the product class like:

```
class Products {
        constructor(name, price, description, img){
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.description = description;
            this.img = img;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create a Manager class:

```
class Manager {
    constructor() {
       this.products = this._createProducts()
    }

    _createProducts() {
        let nike = new Products("Nike", 100, "new-shoes","img/nike.png");
        let adidas = new Products("Adidas", 120, "classic-shoes","img/adidas.png");
        return [nike, adidas]
    }

    sortByName() {
       this.products.sort(function(prod1, prod2) {
          return prod1.name - prod2.name;
       });
    }

    getHTMLRepresentation() {
       productsHTML = this.products.map(function(product) {
            // return html for each product in the array
            return `<div class="info-goods">
            <div class="img"><img src=${item[i].img}></div>
            <div class="name">${item[i].name}</div>
            <div class="price">${item[i].price}</div>
            <div class="description">${item[i].description}</div>
           </div>`
       )));
       return productsHTML;
    }
}
```

Now just create an instance of your manager class and call functions on it:

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
manager.sortByName()
// call a function to create html..
document.querySelector("#products").innerHTML = manager.getHTMLRepresentation();
```